# realloc(): invalid pointer Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c, memory, realloc, coredump

I am working on creating a shell similar to bash. I am running into an error when attempting to get the arguments associated with a command (ie. ls -l). I've searched online and haven't found anything useful.

```
char *userInCopy;
char *ret;
userInCopy = (char*)calloc(1024, sizeof(char));
ret = (char*)calloc(64, sizeof(char));
strcpy(userInCopy, userIn);
int i = 0;
while((ret = strsep(&userInCopy, " "))){
    *(args + i) = (char*)calloc(strlen(ret), sizeof(char));
    strcpy((*(args+i)), ret);
    i++;
    ret = (char*) realloc(ret, (64)* sizeof(char));
}
```

I get input from the user in the char userIn and that is allocated properly. I then parse through the input using strsep getting each argument individually. I can get the ls argument and -l argument but then when it goes to realloc after the -l it gives me the "realloc(): invalid pointer" error. Im lost at why this would work the first time after getting the ls argument but fails after getting the -l argument. Any suggestions?

Comment: The size you give [`realloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) is the new *total* size. It's not how much extra it should add. Also note that you should never assign back to the pointer you pass in, as `realloc` can fail and return `NULL`, in which case you lose the original pointer. Lastly, in C you [should not cast the result of `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/).

Comment: On an unrelated note, the `strsep` function is a POSIX standard function, not a C standard function. Just so you know if you want to use it on other platforms.

Comment: Stylistic point:  Don't use `*(args + i)`.  Instead, use the equivalent, but much clearer, `args[i]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are overwriting the `ret` with `strsep` return value.

```
while((ret = strsep(&userInCopy, " "))) //Here
```

Have a another temporary variable to store `strsep` return.

---

From the [realloc man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc).

> ```
> void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
> ```
>
> `ptr` must have been returned by an earlier call to malloc(), calloc()
>   or realloc().

Comment: but then wouldn't that temporary return value also need to have the memory allocated and reallocated for each iteration of the loop leading me back to the same issue I am in right now?

Comment: No, Your temporary variable doesn't need memory allocation.

Comment: so I would change it too:

    char *temp;
    while((temp = strsep(&userInCopy, " "))){
        ...
        strcpy(args[i], temp);
    }

Comment: @epartridge yes.